# Expected argument of type "int or null", "object" given at property path "id_carrier"

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm working on a Symfony 5.4 project and i have some troubles.

I have already take a look on stackoverflow, but i can't found a solution!

I have a problem, because i have create a form for make a search bar in my page. So, in the form there are multiple input.
In two of this input, i will show values with 2 query (they are two separate entity's, one from a table called "**en_carrier**" and the other one in a table calles **en_order_state**. In the specific, the **ID** of this tables). This two input have to return me **integer** values.

**NOTE**: the form will not interact withe tables en_order_state or en_carrier, but with another table that contain the ID's of these two.

So i thought the best solution would be a **EntityType** for these two, i can create a specific query for obtain all the values.

Apparently, all is correct: label, name and values. But when i submit the form, i get the error

***Expected argument of type "int or null", "object" given at property path "id_carrier".***

How can i resolve this problem?

I decide to structure my form in this way:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
    $builder
        ->add('id_state', IntegerType::class, [
            'required' => false
        ])
        ->add('id_carrier', EntityType::class,  [
            'class' => Carrier::class,
            'required' => false,
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC');
            },
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'choice_value' => function(?Carrier $carrier){
                return $carrier? (int)$carrier->getId():"";
            },
            'label' => 'Corriere',
        ])
        ->add('order_state', EntityType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'class' => OrderState::class,
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('os')
            ->where('os.id_lang = 1')
            ->orderBy('os.state', 'ASC');
        },
        'choice_label' => 'state',
        'choice_value' =>  function(?OrderState $orderState){
            return $orderState? (int)$orderState->getId():"";
        },
        'label' => 'Stato Ordine',
        ])
        ->add('payment', TextType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label text-center'
                )
            ])
        ->add('ps_reference', TextType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label text-center',
                'maxlength' => 9
                )
            ])
        ->add('en_reference', TextType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label text-center'
                )
            ])
        ->add('invoice', ChoiceType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'label' => 'Fattura',
            'choices'  => [
                'no' => false,
                'si' => true
                ]
        ])
        ->add('date', DateType::class, [
            'required' => false
        ])
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class);
    ;
}
```

These are my two entity that i use in the form

Carrier

```
    class Carrier
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id_carrier;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;
```

Order State

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=OrderStateRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Entity @ORM\Table(name="en_order_state") 
 */
class OrderState
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id_state;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $id_lang;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $state;
```

I choise use EntityType because i have a lot of values to show, and i can do this with a query.
But when i submit the form, i get this error:

[image]

Comment: No, i won't change the relationship of table, i need just to get value without edit the table.

Comment: And which is line 268?

Comment: I found the solution, i add "mapped" => false in the paramters of form

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, i want not set the values of form in table of entity's correspondents, so it's enough to add "mapped" => false in the paramters of form.